# Why to use Boolean Variable in this Code?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I am a newby in java and we had an assignment in our class which I do not 
quite understand.

The program should translate entered words into Pig Latin. So each word beginning with a vowel should be displayed as "word + lay" and each word beginning with a consonant should be displayed like "word_without_the_consonant_at_the_beginning + consonant + ay".

My problem is that I do not understand why this needs to 
be included. Can someone explain it to me? Especially since I already 
entered those variables at the beginning of the code.

```
        firstVowelFound = false;
        firstIndex = 0;
```

Why do I need firstVowelFound in this case? And why do I have to inlcude it 
in here:

```
      while ((firstIndex < scannedWords.length()) && !firstVowelFound)
```

This is the code, corrected by the teacher. Those in bold are those, which 
I do not understand. Hopefully you can help me. Thank you!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PigLatin2
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner wordScanner;

    String
      wordInput = "",
      scannedWords = "",
      pigLatinWord = "";

    int
      firstIndex = 0;

    char
      firstLetter;

    boolean
      firstVowelFound = false;

    while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) //as long as there is input, read input.
    {
      wordInput = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
      wordScanner = new Scanner(wordInput);

      while (wordScanner.hasNext()) //read input to find out the words
      {
        scannedWords = wordScanner.next();

        **firstVowelFound = false;
        firstIndex = 0;    


        //for the following part, the program looks for the first Index of 
        //each word. If the letters of switch are included, boolean is 
        //true.

        while ((firstIndex < scannedWords.length()) && !firstVowelFound)**
        {
          firstLetter = scannedWords.charAt(firstIndex);

          switch (firstLetter)
          {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
              **firstVowelFound = true;**
              break;

            default: 
              // no vowel occurred in the word, so look for more words.
              firstIndex++;
          }
         }
        /*the following parts create pigLatin Words. When index is 0, all 
          words starting with a vowel will be word + lay, any other word 
          will display word with the first letter + ay displayed at the end 
          of the word */ 

        if (firstIndex == 0)
        {
          pigLatinWord = scannedWords + "lay";
        }
        else
        {
          pigLatinWord = scannedWords.substring(1) + 
          scannedWords.substring(0,1) + "ay";
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Pig Latin for your entered word is " + 
      pigLatinWord + 
      " ");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a brief explanation on what the code is expected to do?

Comment: The code should change any word entered beginning with a vowel to the word + lay. For each word starting with a consonant, the code should turn the word into word without the consonant at the beginning + consonant + ay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `firstVowelFound` is there to ensure that the while loop breaks when the first vowel is found. Actually without it the loop would be infinite.

Probably the confusing thing in the code is the `break` inside the `switch`. It doesn't make the program to get out of the while loop but just outside of the switch.

Comment: And why do I need to specify firstVowelFound again in the loop? I already gave firstVowelFound a value at the beginning of the code. 

Thank you for the break, that makes a lot more sense now!!

Comment: Let's assume your first word contains a vowel - you set `firstVowelFound` to true to leave the most inner loop, do all the word transormation and then you move to the second word. The new run of the middle while loop starts. Just after the `wordScanner.next();` call, the `firstVowelFound` is already true from the previous loop run. You need to change it to false to get into the most inner loop. I hope I've explained it clearly enough

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!! One more question which occurred during my test run. Why does it only read one word, but not a whole line? where is the problem?

Comment: I've tested your code just now and it almost flowlessly. The only thing is that you're displaying only the last word. The `System.out.println()` call should be in the more nested loop (move the `}` from before the call to after it)